# Can someone help me with my Regex to get the text in html code?

Tags: php, html, regex

I need get the text from text in the html code using regex in php code. But maybe it's seem I wrong somewhere in my code. Please can you help me fix my code. Thank you very much!
This is my regex pattern:

```
/<a\shref="\/vn\/tags\/.*">(?P<tags>.*)<\/a>/
```

And this is example subject:

```
<ul class="clearfix"><li><span class="tagBoxTitle">Từ khóa: </span></li><li><a href="/vn/tags/Th%E1%BB%B1c%20ph%E1%BA%A9m/index.html">Thực phẩm</a>,&nbsp;</li><li><a href="/vn/tags/gi%C3%A1-c%E1%BA%A3/index.html">giá-cả</a>,&nbsp;</li><li><a href="/vn/tags/h%C3%A0ng-ti%C3%AAu-d%C3%B9ng/index.html">hàng-tiêu-dùng</a>,&nbsp;</li><li><a href="/vn/tags/gi%E1%BA%A3m-gi%C3%A1/index.html">giảm-giá</a>,&nbsp;</li><li><a href="/vn/tags/c%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Bc-v%E1%BA%ADn-t%E1%BA%A3i/index.html">cước-vận-tải</a>,&nbsp;</li><li><a href="/vn/tags/gi%C3%A1-x%C4%83ng/index.html">giá-xăng</a>,&nbsp;</li><li><a href="/vn/tags/x%C4%83ng-d%E1%BA%A7u/index.html">xăng-dầu</a>,&nbsp;</li><li><a href="/vn/tags/h%C3%A0ng-h%C3%B3a/index.html">hàng-hóa</a>,&nbsp;</li><li><a href="/vn/tags/CPI/index.html">CPI</a>,&nbsp;</li><li><a href="/vn/tags/T%E1%BA%BFt-nguy%C3%AAn-%C4%91%C3%A1n/index.html">Tết-nguyên-đán</a></li></ul>
```

Hope I can get an answer as soon as possible, thanks again!

Comment: No <- Thats the Answer of the question in your title

Comment: There are some tool like RegExr to help you with Tasks like that

Comment: @j_s_stack sorry can you tell me why? :(

Comment: What's wrong with a html parser?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I used a few test regex online tools with above parser but i couldn't get the text in <a></a> elements

Comment: @DuyNguyen turn all the `.*` to `.*?` https://regex101.com/r/iZ5kC7/6 . Like others said, don't parse html with regex.

Comment: @j_s_stack, great everybody says do not use regex to parse html, got millions of reason why not to. but will it not be helpful to the person asking the question and other if you direct them to a answer that tell what to use to do so.

Comment: I haven't told you do not use regex to parse html, I just said that this Question is wrong here: 1) ist a duplicate 2) With a bit effort you can solve it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

[Don't parse html with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3942918)

If you wanna regex solution then turn all the `.*` to `.*?` in-order to do a non-greedy match.

```
<a\shref="\/vn\/tags\/.*?">(?P<tags>.*?)<\/a>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iZ5kC7/7)